# Using pdb in QGIS console

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, debugging

I am unable to use pdb from qgis console.
If I run a function that calls pdb.set_trace() I get the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "D:\Scripts\routDesigner.py", line 29, in ttt
    pdb.set_trace()
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGISBR~1\apps\Python27\lib\bdb.py", line 53, in trace_dispatch
    return self.dispatch_return(frame, arg)
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGISBR~1\apps\Python27\lib\bdb.py", line 91, in dispatch_return
    if self.quitting: raise BdbQuit
BdbQuit
```

prefixing pdb.set_trace() with  QtCore.pyqtRemoveInputHook() does not change anything. Finally, using pdb.pm() has also strange effects, it seems that it prints (Pdb) and quits the debugging environment before I can write anything.
I'm using qgis 2.6 ob windows 8

Comment: Why do you want to use pdb in the Python console ?

Comment: I don't get your question. To debug code that I am importing into the console?

Comment: pdb if for debugging scripts  (look at [pdb – Interactive Debugger)](http://pymotw.com/2/pdb/)

Comment: sure and that's what I am trying to debug : a script that uses qgis libraries, and that I call from the qgis console.

Comment: The problem is that the console is a PyQT4 "window" and not a classic shell, look at [Debugging a pyQT4 app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1736015/debugging-a-pyqt4-app)

Comment: yes, I've read about it, and that's why I specified that placing QtCore.pyqtRemoveInputHook() did not help. But I guess I will just call it from a normal python interpreter, what is unfortunately nowhere near as easy.